# Python __dir__() doesn't change dir()

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to add '**dir**' method to my object so when dir() is called on it, my function will be called.

My code looks like this:

```
class c(object):
    def __dir__(self):
        return ["a"]
print dir(c())
print c().__dir__()
```

Only the second print shows ["a"], and the first acts like normal.
I've tried this in several ways and sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. Any ideas why?

Edit:
I was missleading, my code is more complex then I showed. To be exact, my code creates an object 'x' with dir method and writing:

```
x.__dir__()
```

Works, but

```
x.__dir__() == dir(x)
```

Returns false

Comment: I tested this right now with python2.7 and it works just fine.

Comment: Cannot reproduce -- can at least some people with the rep vote to close as "cannot be reproduced"? Just upvoting comments doesn't help anything.

Comment: "I've tried this in several ways and sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't." Can you shows us the several ways you've tried this, and show us what each way actually outputs? As said above, the code you've provided appears to work as expected.

Comment: In response to your edit: Are you sure your `__dir__` method is a pure function? As in, it does not modify any state, such as variables anywhere? If it does modify something then a first call might differ from a second call.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are writing `dir(c)` instead of `dir(c())` somewhere. The difference is calling `dir` on a class (`dir(c)`) invokes the class object which itself has a default `__dir__()`, which will give the undesired default behavior. What you have in your question right now (`dir(c())`) should work.